# PHP server "catch-all" requests

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP built-in server for a small, personal project.

I'm just wondering if there's any way to rewrite all requests to just one script, which can then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and similar in order to process different things.

Or, alternatively, is there any way to set a 404 ErrorDocument for the PHP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you start the built in server you can specify a router script (instead of an Apache .htaccess file, as an example).

```
$> php -S localhost:8080 YourRouterDocument.php
```

[The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Aah, how did I miss that when reading the CLI docs? XD Thank you.